# php stripping a string into a paragraph

Tags: php

I have a large string which contains tag elements.i.e: `<h3>`,`p` tags
they have also classes.I want to remove tags and make them into single paragraph.But when i am outputting result i am getting a new line after each tag closing.

### Below is my string code

```
<h3 data-reactid="152">The Host Line: Who's Hosting</h3>
<p data-reactid="153">Traditionally, the bride's parents are the hosts of the wedding, and are named at the top of the invitation, even for very formal affairs. However, including the names of both sets of parents as hosts is a gracious option no matter who foots the bill. Also, more and more couples these days are hosting their own weddings, or do so together with their parents.</p>
```

When i am applying strip tags i am getting like:

```
The Host Line: Who's Hosting
Traditionally, the bride's parents are the hosts.....
```

Getting into new line after `Hosting`
But i am wanting like:

```
The Host Line: Who's Hosting Traditionally, the bride's parents are the hosts.....
```

> Also apostrophe is causing a problem here

Comment: The original string have a line break after the `</h3>` and since you only strip tags, there's no reason why the line break would disappear. If you want to remove the line break, you could simply do: `$text = str_replace("\n", ' ', $text);` (assuming that your string is in the variable `$text`). That would replace the line break with a space instead.

Comment: Yess! It works now...